# C Program to Accept n Integers in an Array and Search for a Specific Number

Tags: arrays, c, integer

**(Motivation)** I am trying to construct a program in C that allows me to
(1) Enter a certain amount of numbers in an array
(2) Enter what exactly those numbers are
(3) Enter a search value from that array that makes the C program find what position that search value is in.

Basically, I am trying to do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8ccaJu0eXI&t=16s).

**(Attempt)** Here is what I tried so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Write a 'C' program to accept n integers in an array and search for a specific number.

int main()
{
    int a[10],n,i,key;
    printf("Enter how many numbers in an array: ");
    scanf("&d",&n);
    printf("Accept n numbers in an array: \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("&d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("Display Array Elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter search value: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==key)
        printf("Number found at position %d", i+1);
        else
        printf("Element not found!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this in CodeBlocks (version 20.03), I am able to enter in how many numbers there are in an array, but then after typing in a number, say 4, CodeBlocks prints out

Accept n numbers in an array: 4

Display Array Elements

Enter search value:

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 22.628 s

Press any key to continue.

**(Question)** How can I improve this code such that it does what (1), (2), and (3) above says? I also welcome alternate methods. I have been trying to replicate what the YouTube video in the link says, but I have not been able to succeed.

I want to mention I have little to no coding experience, and I am learning C for the first time. I also tried searching for similar questions, but given my novice skills in coding, I am not able to take advantage of them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using `scanf()` or relatives, always always always check its return value to make sure it succeeded before trying to use variables it sets.

Comment: And maybe re-read its documentation to see what the format string is supposed to look like.

Comment: `scanf("&d"` should be `scanf("%d",` in both places it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these problems:

**Code not compiled with a well enabled compiler**

Use a compiler with all warnings enabled.  This rapidly points out many of code's troubles.

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
scanf("&d", &n);
      ^~~~

warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
scanf("&d", &a[i]);
       ^~~~

warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]
printf("%d", &a[i]);
```

**Code attempts to print the address and not the value**

Printing with `"%d"` and an address and not an `int` leads to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Drop the `&`.

```
// printf("%d",&a[i]);
printf("%d", a[i]);
```

**Use `%`**  [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75396284/c-program-to-accept-n-integers-in-an-array-and-search-for-a-specific-number/75399599#comment133035444_75396284)

Since `&d` is not a specifier, `"&d"` directs `scanf()` to scan in the characters `'&'` and `'d'` and then move on.  If there or not, code simply moved on and used an  uninitialized `n` for the rest of code.  In OP's case, `n` appears to be 0 and so code ended promptly.

```
// scanf("&d",&a[i]);
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
//     ^
```

**Test inputs**

- Check `scanf()` return value. [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75396284/c-program-to-accept-n-integers-in-an-array-and-search-for-a-specific-number/75399599#comment133035381_75396284)
- Test range

```
// scanf("&d",&n);
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1 || n > 10) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Invalid numeric input or out of range 1-10\n");
  return EXT_FAILULRE;
}
```